# How do I move the mount point of a drive

Tags: mount, chroot

I have `/dev/sda2` mounted as `/mnt`.
I am actually running my system from a volume mounted at `/mnt/install` (I've chrooted to `/mnt/install`).

I'd like to be able to use that disk from within my chrooted linux.  How do I move `/dev/sda2` from `/mnt` to `/mnt/install/mnt/fast`?

Comment: I think you are going to be out of luck here.

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to do but: You have tried with `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/install/mnt/fast` ? The `/install/mnt/fast` folder must exist previously.

Comment: is your chrooted system inside sda2?

Answer (score 1):

Is your chrooted system inside /dev/sda2? if not, just create that folder and mount to it

Outside the chroot enviroment,

first, unmount the current folder

```
sudo umount /mnt/install
```

then, make the new mount point directory

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/install/mnt/fast
```

finally re-mount the partition to your new mountpoint

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/install/mnt/fast
```

now, you should be able to chroot and access files at /mnt/fast